# Different results between matrix operations in MATLAB and Python

Tags: python, matlab, numpy, matrix-multiplication, pca

I am implementing PCA between a set of generated images and suppressing the background of the images using the selected principal components.  I have implemented this in MATLAB and receive exactly the results I was expecting.  But when I implement this in Python my results are much different. The process is as follows, I first generate my image dataset, perform the PCA on the dataset, calculate and subtract the background from the images in the dataset, and then reshape my dataset and compare my results to the original.  Below is my function performing the PCA on the original dataset.

```
def pca_images(total_images, count, size, num_pcs):
    flat_images = np.empty([count, size*size])
    # unravel structure of the image
    for i in range(0,count):
        flat_images[i] = np.ravel(total_images[i])
    # calculate covariance matrix
    cov_mat = np.cov(flat_images.T)
    # eigenvectors and eigenvalues of the covariance matrix
    eig_val_cov, eig_vec_cov = np.linalg.eig(cov_mat)
    # sort the (eigenvalue, eigenvector) lists from low to high
    inds = eig_val_cov.argsort()
    # flip around and sort eigenvectors high to low
    eig_vec_cov = eig_vec_cov[inds[::-1]]
    # take num_pcs number of eigenvectors
    components = eig_vec_cov[:,0:num_pcs]
    # create list to store background for each image
    bg = []
    # find principal components
    for i in range(0,count):
        bg.append(np.dot(np.dot(components.T,flat_images[i]),components.T))
    # allocate array to hold filtered images
    images_suppressed = []
    # filter out background from each image and store
    for i in range(0,count):
        images_suppressed.append(flat_images[i] - bg[i])
    return images_suppressed
```

When I compare this to my MATLAB code the difference appears to be occurring in the `bg` matrix found in the `pca_images` function.  In MATLAB this matrix contains only real values but in Python it is filled with real and complex values.  In MATLAB the results show the `images_suppressed` pixels are all less then the original image pixel values since a `bg` value is being subtracted from the original image.  Yet in Python some of my `images_suppressed` values are larger then the original image pixel values despite the subtraction and this leads to noise actually being added to my images.  The MATLAB code used to find the `bg` matrix is below:

```
%// CALCULATE THE COVARIANCE MATRIX BETWEEN ALL IMAGES
total_cov = cov(total);
%// FIND THE 6 LARGEST MAGNITUDE EIGENVALUES
[V,D] = eigs(total_cov);
%// FIND PRINCIPAL COMPONENTS AND REMOVE BACKGROUND
proc_total = total;
v = V(:,1:m)';                      %'// TAKE TOP M EIGENVECTORS
for i=1:m
    z = proc_total(i,:);            %// TAKE ORIGINAL DATA
    [size(v), size(z')]             %'// VERIFY SIZES FOR MULTIPLICATION
    bg =  v * z';                   %'// FIND PRINCIPAL COMPONENT
    [size(bg'), size(v)]            %'// VERIFY SIZES FOR MULTIPLICATION
    bg = bg' * v;                   %'
    proc_total(i,:) = proc_total(i,:) - bg;  %// REMOVE BACKGROUND FROM ORIGINAL DATA
end

%// RESHAPE IMAGE 1
image_final = reshape(proc_total(1,:),n,n);
```

I know the issue has to do with this `bg` matrix and I haven't been able to find anything that would explain why the multiplication of my eigenvectors with the original dataset is giving me different results in MATLAB and Python.  Can anyone explain to me why this is happening ??

Comment: Are you sure that both operations are dot products? It seems to me that your first np.dot should be an np.outer.

Comment: So if I create a 25x25 image then that sequence of code would be a (5x625) dotted with a (625) or a vector and then this result would be a (5) dotted with a (5x625).  I thought that an outer product was multiplication of a row vector and a column vector ?

Comment: Dot is row x col, and you expect a scalar as a result. Outer is col x row, and ou expect a matrix as a result. But I didn't check your code more deeply, that's why I don't post an answer. So maybe you don't need an outer, or maybe you need two of them. It's just that something similar happened to me very recently and dot x outer was the problem. You'll need to check.

Comment: Are you sure you are doing exactly the same thing?  The equivalent of MATLAB's `eigs` seems to be `scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs`.  Have you tried doing the equivalent of your Python algorithm with MATLAB's `eig`, or vice versus?  Also, in my test the maximum `imag` part of the Python results was on the order of `e-15`, so your imaginary parts may be negligible.  Also  make sure you don't have the axes mixed up.

Comment: @TheBlackCat MATLAB eigs is returning the top 6 magnitude eigenvalues and corresponding eigenvectors of the covariance matrix in this case.  In my python code I find all of the eigenvalues and eigenvectors and then sort and extract the ones I want myself.  I was not aware of `scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs` .. that would cut down on three lines of code plus comments. Thank you !!

Comment: @TheBlackCat I implemented `scipy.sparse.linalg.eigs` and am still receiving the same results.  I did have to transpose my dataset for finding the covariance matrix when going from MATLAB to Python due to the way the `numpy.cov` creates the covariance matrix compared to MATLAB.

Comment: @TheBlackCat @rcpinto I found the issue.  In MATLAB I transposed my image data into a col vector and then the first matrix multiplication had to be transposed into a row vector.  I failed to do these transposes in my Python code.  By doing `bg.append(np.dot(np.dot(components.T,flat_images[i].T).T,components.T))` my output was corrected.  Is this a bug in numpy? The documentation for `numpy.dot` says it is equivalent to matrix multiplication for 2D arrays but if this is the case then it should have never allowed the operation to continue if I was multiplying a (5x625) with a (1x625).

Comment: @TheBlackCat @rcpinto Also When I previously checked my array shape using `.shape` the result just showed `(625)` and did not specify whether it was a column vector or row vector and I failed to check it at the time.  Why would it not show as a `(1,625)` or a `(625,1)`?  It wasn't until I started using my variable explorer to visually check the data that I noticed the issue.

Comment: @bartathalon: numpy has something called "automatic broadcasting".  It will automatically duplicate an array along length-1 dimensions when doing calculations against another array where the corresponding dimension has a length great than one.  So when multiplying a `5x625` array by a `1x625` array, the `1x625` array is duplicated 5 times along dimension 1 to match the size of the `5x625` array.  It is similar to MATLAB's `bsxfun`, but it happens automatically.  It is an extension of how scalars work (so how a `1x1` array can be multiplied by a `NxM` array).  MATLAB R2016b will do this too.